# How to assign 1 unique number for rows containing the same value

Tags: sql, oracle

Appreciate if you can help me with a case that I'm working on on `Oracle` (pl/sql).

Suppose I have 1 table named TableA:[TableA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okrHd.png)

The rule of `TableA` sorting is :

1. `CASE_ID` & `CONTRACT` with 'SD' TRIGGER have to be placed on top, regardless of the `SCORE`.
2. After all of the `CONTRACT` & `CASE_ID` with 'SD' TRIGGER are placed on top, the next CASE_ID & CONTRACT are sorted by SCORE descending.

I want to place 1 unique number for 1 `CASE_ID`, ascending from 1, so CONTRACT with the same `CASE_ID` will have the same number. an Example of the solution that I'm trying to obtain is :[Example Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSZzZ.png)

I have tried using `DENSE_RANK` with the following query:

```
select a.*
      ,dense_rank() over (partition by a.case_id order by rn) 
  from (
        select a.*,rownum as rn from TableA a
       )a
```

But the solution still is not the way I want it to be, there are some `CASE_ID` assigned with the same NUMBER

Appreciate if you can give me some input regarding this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Always post sample data  and expected o/p as text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

Dense Rank with a partition would just give you consecutive ranks in a partition. To use dense_rank without partition refer to *Gordon's* answer.

One other way is to create a row_number over distinct case_id and join back to original table;

```
SELECT TableA.* , bar.NUMBER
FROM TableA
JOIN 
(SELECT foo.CASE_ID as case_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by 1) as NUMBER
FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT CASE_ID FROM TableA)as foo) as bar
ON TableA.CASE_ID = bar.case_id ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Mankind_008 that really helped me !

Comment: Welcome to the community, also to use dense_rank properly for your case refer Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dense_rank()`.  It looks like:

```
select a.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by a.case_id) 
from TableA a;
```

No `partition by` is needed.

Comment: Nice. i didn't knew we could use it without partition. Thanks. +1

Comment: Hi @Gordon, Thank you for your help!

a bit more question, If I use dense_rank like you mentioned, the order of the Table A changes, it gives a unique number for each case_id. Suppose I want case_id 123 to be numbered 1, 234 to be numbered 2, 345 to be numbered 3 and so on, ordered like the original order, is there anyway for it using dense_rank? Thank you

Comment: @user9789046 . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no such thing as the "original order".  If you have a column that specifies the ordering, then it is possible.  However, I would suggest that you ask another question with a more appropriate set of sample data.